# What is the range of the linear operator $T:C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ defined by $T(f(x))=g(x)=\int_0^xf(s)\,ds$? And show this is one-to-one

Tags: functional-analysis

What I did is the following:
If $f\neq g$, then there exists $x_0 \in (0,1)$ and there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 +\epsilon)$. But, I could not show that the integral should be different from this point. Can you help me regarding this?

About the range, the image function should have the value $0$ at $0$. Moreover, by FTC, we have, 
$$G(x)=\int_0^xf(s)\,ds \Rightarrow g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$$
where $G^{\prime}(x)=g(x)$. Therefore, I want to say that the range of this operator is the set of functions which have antiderivatives and $g(0)=0$. But, I am not sure. Can you help me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For injectivity it suffices to show that $\ker T=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of $T$ is the set of functions $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that:

- $f(0)=0$;
- $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continuous.

In fact, if $f$ is such a function, then $f=T(f')$. And it is clear that every function from the range of $T$ has those two properties.

Comment: What about the injectivity?

Comment: It is injective, because if $T(f)=0$, then the map $x\mapsto\int_0^xf(s)\,\mathrm ds$ is the null map. So, if you differentiate it, you get the null map again. But $(\int_0^xf(s)\,\mathrm ds)'=f(x)$.